# SQL Oracle: Фильтрация по условиям в группе

Tags: sql, oracle

Имею таблицу следующего вида,

```
   a   b   c   d    f
  apple qw  er null null
  apple qw  er 123 456
  pear  ed  rt 342 234
  pear  ed  rt 675 897
  pear  ed  rt 786 876
  plum ed  rt null null
  plum ed  rt null null
```

на выходе пытаюсь получить:

```
   a   b   c   d    f
  apple qw  er null null
  apple qw  er 123 456
```

возможно ли как-то в селекте отфильтровать строки группы,
при этом в этой группе должна быть хотя бы по одной строке со значением `null` и не равно `null` для колонки `d`,
в какую сторону лучше смотреть? возможно ли как-то получить через `case` или в сторону оконных функций?

Comment: Ай, я не туда посмотрел и написал ответ для `Pandas` под `Python` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte As (
    SELECT a,b,c,d,f,
           SUM(CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c) non_nulls,
           SUM(CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b,c) nulls
    FROM test
)
SELECT a,b,c,d,f
FROM cte
WHERE nulls > 0 AND non_nulls > 0
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2f7e04c5ffa80fa693d29f132099003